# CKEditor not editable in IE11 after ajax call

Tags: ajax, ckeditor, internet-explorer-11

Example:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wq86gqs/11/)

If the page is loaded the first time, the CKEditor is working right and the value of the editor can be edited. After hitting the button "ajax" which is calling the following function (cursor must be in the editor field):

```
function ajax_call() {    
    var html = "<textarea id=\"textarea\"><p>test 1</p><p>test 2</p><p>test 3</p></textarea><script type='text/javascript'>jQuery(document).ready(function() { ckEditor('textarea'); });<\/script>";

    $.post("/echo/html/", { html: html }, function(data){
        jQuery('#target').html(data);
    });
}
```

it isn't possible to click on the text in IE11 to edit the value. Clicking beyond the text or left of it enabels the editor again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like creation of new textarea after CKEDITOR is initiated brakes editor in IE. Though i just tried to set data directly on instance of CKEDITOR and it worked fine,rather than creating new textarea tag.

```
 function ajax_call() {

    var html = "<p>test 4</p><p>test 5</p><p>test 6</p>";

    $.post("/echo/html/", { html: html }, function(data){
        //jQuery('#target').html(data); <-- Removed from original
        CKEDITOR.instances['textarea'].setData(data)// <-- Added

    });
}            

function ckEditor(id) {
    CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
        language : 'de',
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ckEditor('textarea');

});
```

Here is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2wq86gqs/15/